# Retrieve the list of all possible supported operations for spring JPA that auto builds the query

Tags: database, spring, spring-data-jpa

So I have a JPA repository class that operates on an entity. The spring docs dont provide all possible operations I can do on the object which automatically builds the derived queries.

So if I have

```
findByLastName
```

I need to know what else is supported in place of 'find' as everything after 'By' above is retrieved from the entity.

Is there any reference to the list of all possible operations supported on an entity?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html

Comment: This does give me an exhaustive list - like I see that you can do removeBy* where removeBy does not exist in any of the interfaces JPARepository extends

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [query method document](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.query-methods) 
Some example query method:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {

  List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);

  // Enables the distinct flag for the query
  List<Person> findDistinctPeopleByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);
  List<Person> findPeopleDistinctByLastnameOrFirstname(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling ignoring case for an individual property
  List<Person> findByLastnameIgnoreCase(String lastname);
  // Enabling ignoring case for all suitable properties
  List<Person> findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String firstname);

  // Enabling static ORDER BY for a query
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);
  List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameDesc(String lastname);
}
```

Comment: As above - this only gives a few examples - not an exhaustive list. Like I want to ensure the query I am writing is not something that's already implemented via reflection using query methods that JPA automatically provide.

Comment: Currently, Spring JPA also supports `deleteBy`, `count`. They were added in [version 1.6.0.RC1](https://spring.io/blog/2014/05/21/what-s-new-in-spring-data-dijkstra) but the weird thing is they were added in change log but not in document.

Comment: great - does anyone know if there is a way to request them to enhance their doc?